# How do I hide link text if the href is blank?

Tags: jquery, css, href

I have a series of links being generated and some have a blank href.
I want to .hide the blanks or maybe even if it appears to have a # using Jquery and/or CSS

The links look like

```
<a class="Highlighted" id="hyperlinkViewProfile" href="">text to hide</a>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "links being generated" ?
If you are using jquery to generate links then where you are generating you can add $(this).attr("href", "#");

Answer (score 11):

With CSS:

```
A[href=""], A[href="#"], A:not([href]) {
  display: none;
}
```

This works for links with no href or with href="#". If you want to match links with a # **anywhere** in the href, use `A[href~="#"]`

Didn't test in old browsers, you may resort to jquery selectors in that case.

Answer (score 2):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Kfp3L/)

```
$('a').filter(function(){return $(this).attr('href') === "" || $(this).attr('href') === "#"}).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple jQuery:

```
$("a[href=''], a:not([href])").hide();
```

Could modify the selector to include `#` links as well:

```
$("a[href=''], a:not([href]), a:[href='#']").hide();
```